# Is Google charts are working in SharePoint 2019 or not?

Tags: sharepoint-2019

We are planning to migrate the applications from SP2013 to SP2019 , In our SP 2013 applications we have a google charts, I just want to confirm that SharePoint 2019 supports the Google charts or not? I read many blogs but I have not found a clear answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

Use *Content Editor* to JavaScript or CSS in SharePoint 2019, [should work on](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/google-pie-chart-sharepoint/).